# pdfcrop fails to run on a file

Tags: pdftex, pdfcrop

I'm trying to remove the huge margins on the following PDF file for two pages per sheet printing:

http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGaug1612public.pdf

When I run:

```
$ pdfcrop FOAGaug1612public.pdf test.pdf
```

I get the following output:

---

```
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdftex.fmt
fmtutil: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdftex -progname=pdftex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfetex.ini' ...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2013/dev) (INITEX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/cp227.tcx)
entering extended mode
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/config/pdfetex.ini
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf/tex/generic/config/pdftexconfig.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/etex/etex.src
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,
macros, math definitions, output routines, hyphenation
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex
[skipping from \patterns to end-of-file...]))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/etex/etexdefs.lib
Skipping module "grouptypes"; Loading module "interactionmodes";
Skipping module "nodetypes"; Skipping module "iftypes";)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf/tex/generic/config/language.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-pl.tex
QX Polish hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-qx.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-pl.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-ru.tex
T2A Russian hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/ruhyphen.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/catkoi.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/koi2t2a.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/ruhyphal.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/cyryoal.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/hypht2.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-uk.tex
T2A Ukrainian hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ukrhyph/ukrhyph.tex
Ukrainian hyphenation patterns in t2a encoding
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ukrhyph/catlcy.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ukrhyph/lcy2t2a.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ukrhyph/ukrhypmp.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/hypht2.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-ca.tex
EC Catalan hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-ca.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-sk.tex
EC Slovak hyphenation patterns (Jana Chlebikova, 1992)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-sk.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-nl.tex
EC Dutch hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-nl.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-hu.tex
EC Hungarian hyphenation patterns (v20110815)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-hu.tex
Huhyphn - hungarian hyphenation patterns v20110815))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-bg.tex
T2A Bulgarian hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-t2a.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-bg.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-rm.tex
ASCII Romansh hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-rm.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-af.tex
EC Afrikaans hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-af.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-tk.tex
EC Turkmen hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-tk.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-tr.tex
EC Turkish hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-tr.tex))
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \chardef 
<to be read again> 
                   \rhm@arabic 
\addlanguage ...\chardef \csname rhm@#1\endcsname 
                                                  =#5 \uselanguage {#1}\inpu...
l.43 \addlanguage{arabic}{zerohyph.tex}{}{}{}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \chardef 
<to be read again> 
                   \rhm@arabic 
\addlanguage ...\chardef \csname rhm@#1\endcsname 
                                                  =#5 \uselanguage {#1}\inpu...
l.43 \addlanguage{arabic}{zerohyph.tex}{}{}{}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on pdftex.log.
Error: `pdftex -ini  -jobname=pdftex -progname=pdftex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfetex.ini' failed

###############################################################################
fmtutil: Error! Not all formats have been built successfully.
Visit the log files in directory
  /home/efagerho/.texlive2012/texmf-var/web2c
for details.
###############################################################################

This is a summary of all `failed' messages:
`pdftex -ini  -jobname=pdftex -progname=pdftex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfetex.ini' failed
warning: kpathsea: mktexfmt output `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2013/dev) (INITEX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/cp227.tcx)
entering extended mode
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/config/pdfetex.ini
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf/tex/generic/config/pdftexconfig.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/etex/etex.src
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,
macros, math definitions, output routines, hyphenation
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex
[skipping from \patterns to end-of-file...]))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/etex/etexdefs.lib
Skipping module "grouptypes"; Loading module "interactionmodes";
Skipping module "nodetypes"; Skipping module "iftypes";)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf/tex/generic/config/language.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-pl.tex
QX Polish hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-qx.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-pl.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-ru.tex
T2A Russian hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/ruhyphen.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/catkoi.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/koi2t2a.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/ruhyphal.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/cyryoal.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/hypht2.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-uk.tex
T2A Ukrainian hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ukrhyph/ukrhyph.tex
Ukrainian hyphenation patterns in t2a encoding
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ukrhyph/catlcy.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ukrhyph/lcy2t2a.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ukrhyph/ukrhypmp.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ruhyphen/hypht2.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-ca.tex
EC Catalan hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-ca.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-sk.tex
EC Slovak hyphenation patterns (Jana Chlebikova, 1992)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-sk.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-nl.tex
EC Dutch hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-nl.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-hu.tex
EC Hungarian hyphenation patterns (v20110815)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-hu.tex
Huhyphn - hungarian hyphenation patterns v20110815))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-bg.tex
T2A Bulgarian hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-t2a.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-bg.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-rm.tex
ASCII Romansh hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-rm.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-af.tex
EC Afrikaans hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-af.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-tk.tex
EC Turkmen hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-tk.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-tr.tex
EC Turkish hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/conversions/conv-utf8-ec.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-tr.tex))
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \chardef 
<to be read again> 
                   \rhm@arabic 
\addlanguage ...\chardef \csname rhm@#1\endcsname 
                                                  =#5 \uselanguage {#1}\inpu...
l.43 \addlanguage{arabic}{zerohyph.tex}{}{}{}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \chardef 
<to be read again> 
                   \rhm@arabic 
\addlanguage ...\chardef \csname rhm@#1\endcsname 
                                                  =#5 \uselanguage {#1}\inpu...
l.43 \addlanguage{arabic}{zerohyph.tex}{}{}{}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on pdftex.log.' instead of a filename.
!!! Error: pdfTeX run failed!
```

Comment: Where did you get that version of pdftex (`TeX Live 2013/dev`)?

Answer (score 2):

The error messages show, that the format generation for plain pdfTeX failed.
Try

```
fmtutil --byfmt pdftex
```

If it succeeds, then you can try `pdfcrop` again. Otherwise, try updating the TeX distribution, perhaps the error is already fixed.

`pdfcrop` can also be used without format:

```
$ pdfcrop --ini FOAGaug1612public.pdf test.pdf
```

The file `FOAGaug1612public.pdf` contains pages without contents that cause some warnings and the `xref` table is not correct for some entries. And the file was generated by LaTeX with lots of overfull `\hboxes`. Apart from this you should get a cropped `test.pdf`.

Comment: Sorry for my naive question, for me, I must use `--ini` in order to make `pdfcrop` work. Otherwise, I get an error `pdfTeX run failed with value 1!`. Could you please tell me why? I couldn't figure it out from the short help.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Then, very likely the format file for the plain format of pdfTeX is missing. The procedure of the format generation depends on the TeX distribution. BTW, this is the reason for option `--ini` to get independent from format files.

Comment: I am sorry, but what does the text plain format file have to do with cropping a PDF file? Does `pdfcrop` get some information from it about the layout or something else of latex-ouput PDF file? Also, the error shows up again with `luatex`. so do I have to look for these format files or the cropped file quality is independent of their existence?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou `pdfcrop` uses a TeX compiler to read and create the modified PDF file. The TeX format is either the "plain" format (not the LaTeX format) for the supported TeX compilers (pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX) or `pdfcrop` can be used with option `--ini` without any preloaded format. If you do not know, how to create format files, then ask a new question (with information about the used TeX distribution); this is way off-topic for this question.